# Resizing vector of object of nested class inside abstract class

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, polymorphism

I am trying to build a Hex Game using the Polymorphism principle. I have a class inside an abstract class. I need a 2D vector of Cells (nested class) but I'm getting this error when I try to implement a function to resize my vector.

> Base and Abstract Class = AbstractHex || Nested Class = Cell || Derived
> Class = HexVector

*Here's what I got (ERROR):*

`` /usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccq9PAk3.o: in function `void std::_Construct<HexGame::AbstractHex::Cell>(HexGame::AbstractHex::Cell*)':HexVector.cpp:(.text._ZSt10_ConstructIN7HexGame11AbstractHex4CellEJEEvPT_DpOT0_[_ZSt10_ConstructIN7HexGame11AbstractHex4CellEJEEvPT_DpOT0_]+0x2d): undefined reference to `HexGame::AbstractHex::Cell::Cell()' collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status ``

*My Base Class (Abstract):*

```
namespace HexGame{
   class AbstractHex{

     public:
        class Cell{
                public:
                    explicit Cell();
                    explicit Cell(int rw,int col) : row(rw) , column(col){} //INTENTIONALLY EMPTY
                    explicit Cell(int rw,int col, char p) : row(rw) , column(col) , point(p){} 
                                         //INTENTIONALLY EMPTY
                    int getRow()const {return row;};
                    int getColumn()const {return column;};
                    void setRow(int index) {row = index;};
                    void setColumn(int index) {column = index;};
                    int getPoint()const {return point;};
                    void setPoint(char param) {point = param;};    
                private:
                    int row;
                    int column;
                    char point;
            };

     virtual void setSize() = 0;

     private:
       int board_size;
```

I'm calling setSize() function which is in abstract class. **Can I call a virtual function within a non-virtual function which is in abstract class?**

```
void AbstractHex::startGame(){ //non-virtual function in Abstract Class
setSize(); //virtual function in Abstract Class
//I'm calling startGame() function every time I create an object of HexVector
}
```

*My Derived Class:*

```
class HexVector : public AbstractHex{
    public:
        void setSize() override;
    private:
        vector<vector<AbstractHex::Cell> > board;
```

*Overriding of setSize() function*

```
void HexVector::setSize(){
 board.resize(getBoardSize());
    for(int i=0; i<getBoardSize(); i++){
        board[i].resize(getBoardSize());
    }
}
```

Comment: "Can I call a virtual function within a non-virtual function which is in abstract class?" - Can you explain the question? "..which is.." - this part. A virtual function is an abstract class or a non-virtual function is an abstract class. This does not make sense to me.

Comment: @yvw I want to call a pure virtual function in a non-virtual function. Both functions are in abstract class. In my example I have startGame() function (non-virtual) and setSize() function (virtual). I need to call setSize() but it will be in a startGame() function. I think the summary of my question is that "Can I use virtual functions in abstract class or can I allowed to use them only in derived classes?"

Comment: You can use any function of a base class in a derived classes, if such function have a definition.

Comment: And you do not give a definition to the above function. The linker tells you about it.

Comment: @yvw but I override the setSize() in HexVector and I shared the functions. What function is missing? I checked again but I did not see :/ There are definitions of setSize() in HexVector and startGame() in AbstractHex. Also, there are declarations of both of them in AbstractHex and HexVector.

Comment: What exactly led you to believe that the link failure has anything to do with calling "a virtual function within a non-virtual function which is in abstract class"? The link error has absolutely nothing to do with that, whatsoever, but with the fact that you forgot to define the class's default constructor. That's literally what the link failure error message says.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I thought like that way because when I delete the function setSize() then my code compiled without an error. Thanks for your advice so I solved my problem by adding curly brackets after the declaration of default constructor.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem. The main reason is that my default constructor of the **Cell** class is not defined. When I defined that default constructor (I simply added 2 curly brackets after the declaration of constructor in class) my problem has been solved.

Before:

```
class Cell{
            public:
                explicit Cell();
```

After:

```
class Cell{
            public:
                explicit Cell(){}; //CURLY BRACKETS FOR DEFINITION
```